# Overpass turbo, Get center of area

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have this query for overpass turbo ,

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="AM"][admin_level~"2"]->.search;
(way(area.search)[place~"town|city"];
 rel(area.search)[place~"town|city"];
)->.w;
.w map_to_area->.e;
.e out center tags;
```

This quer returns node like this:

```
{
  "type": "area",
  "id": 3610255555,
  "tags": {
    "admin_level": "6",
    "boundary": "administrative",
    "name": "Եղեգնաձոր",
    "name:de": "Jeghegnadsor",
    "name:en": "Yeghegnadzor",
    "name:hy": "Եղեգնաձոր",
    "name:it": "Jeghegnadzoras",
    "name:ja": "イェゲグナゾル",
    "name:pl": "Jeghegnadzor",
    "name:ru": "Ехегнадзор",
    "name:uk": "Єгеґнадзор",
    "place": "town",
    "population": "7944",
    "type": "boundary",
    "wikidata": "Q39538",
    "wikipedia": "hy:Եղեգնաձոր"
  }
},
```

How can I get lat and lng of this area or the center of area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Areas" is an Overpass API internal artifact, which is not suitable to calculate a center point for. Instead you want to determine the center using `out center;` for both ways and relations:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="AM"][admin_level~"2"]->.search;
wr(area.search)[place~"^(town|city)$"];
out center;
```

Comment: but this query will return 2 points on the map, 1 relation and 1 way https://ibb.co/q1QZS6S @mmd

Comment: That’s totally expected if the same town has been mapped as both way and relation. It’s a data issue. You need to deal with this in your post processing step.